# チートシートを作成したいが、目当てのサイトが見当たらない

Tags: linux, vim, google-chrome

私は添付画像のようなスタイルのチートシートを作りたいです。ですが、チートシートを作成するサイトが少なく、困っています。皆さんがチートシートを作るときに使っているサイトはどんなサイトでしょうか？？ちなみにhttps://cheatography.com/
は日本語対応してないので、私が作成したチートシートをダウンロードしようとすると日本語で記載した箇所だけ表記が消えてしまうため選択肢にありません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: プログラムで解決するべき内容はなくて、チートシートを作成出力できるサービスを探しているということですか？タグにlinuxとかvimとかのタグもありますが、あまり関係ないということですかね？

Comment: その認識で間違いないです。チートシートを作成出力できるサービスを探していますが、適切なものが見当たらず、皆さんはどうやって作っているのか気になったので質問をさせていただきました。質問の場所が適切でないのであれば申し訳ないです。